# The depth of a map call in R seems unintuitive

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

It seems that the natural depth of the map function in R is not what one would expect.

Reprex:

```r
data = list(
  a =list(
    '1' <- c(1, 2),
    '2' <- c(3,4)
    ),
  b = list(
    '3' <- c(5,6),
    '4' <- c(7,8)
  ) 
)
```

I want to uppercase the names of the list and print them out, but this doesn't work.

```r
map(data, ~str_to_upper(names(.x)))
```

Instead I have to do this:

```r
map_depth(data,.depth = 0, ~str_to_upper(names(.x)))
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You're not really mapping a function to each element of `data` here, I don't know that `map` really helps. You could do something like `map_chr(names(data), str_to_upper)`, but then you're just doing it in a non-vectorized way.

Answer (score 2):

The input to `map` is the underlying list which for first iteration is

```
data[[1]]
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4
```

This has no names in it hence it fails.

When you pass

```
map_depth(data,.depth = 0, ~str_to_upper(names(.x)))
```

The input for first iteration is

```
data[1]
#$a
#$a[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#$a[[2]]
#[1] 3 4
```

which has names and hence it prints them.

You can directly use

```
stringr::str_to_upper(names(data))
#[1] "A" "B"
```

Or in base R

```
toupper(names(data))
```